# Get JSON data from a specific URL in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

What Im trying to do is get the data from this specific url https://www.globalmoneyworld.com/global-media-blog

Once I get the JSON data, Im positive I know how to use it. Ive made several apps in class that touch on this, one was a weather app, the other pulled blog posts from the guardian. The guardian app was more of what I waned to learn than the weather app.

The problem Im running into is that I cannot figure out how to ask for the data. How to get this type of response

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

this is the link I want to get the data from again

https://www.globalmoneyworld.com/global-media-blog

What kind of request do I need to type in using Alamofire to get JSON data from that specific url? And please guide me in the right direction if Im not asking the right question.

Comment: It sounds like you are scraping data, as that URL is not an endpoint that returns well-formed data. Your best bet is to research "web scraping" and/or investigate something like "Beautiful Soup". Otherwise, you are going to have to provide a [mcve] and ask a specific question about that code. See [ask].

Comment: Your first example appears to be an example of an API response. If your target website doesn't offer APIs then you are out of luck to get data in that format. Sure, you could parse the html response but that is terrible hack and would make a very fragile app that could break at any time. Your time would be better spent looking into the twitter or facebook APIs because they have those social media accounts and both of those media companies have solid API calls. YOu would then get your data using the social media APIs as a proxy to what you want...and your app wont break at slightest web change.

Comment: @TravisActon thanks! That was another thing I wanted to ask, but I’m new to stack overflow, and one of my last questions got flagged as too broad so I left it out. So, from my understanding, if the site doesn’t have an official API, then theres no point in trying to scrape data, because if something on the actual page changes, your app breaks? I’m looking into the facebook API now and I think Ive found a way to grab the posts from a facebook page. This is all really new to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you linked returns HTML data, not JSON.

There is no type of request you can make using Alamofire that will give you JSON from an arbitrary URL. The only URLs that return JSON are from sites that allow queries that return JSON. The good news is that JSON is widely supported as a data exchange protocol.